# Make modal popup just big enough, with scrollbar if needed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Due to reasons beyond my control, we're still using Bootstrap 2.3.2. I have a modal popup that might display anywhere from 1 to 50 lines of information. I made it the maximum size I could to fit on the screen and made the middle part, the `.modal-body` have a scrollbar if needed. My HTML looks like:

```
<div id="confirm-popup" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="confirm-popup-subject" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="confirm-popup-subject">XXX</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" id="confirm-content">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button id="confirm-popup-edit" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal"
    aria-hidden="true">Edit</button>
    <button id="confirm-popup-cancel" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal"
    aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <button id="confirm-popup-submit" class="btn btn-primary"
    aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal">Create Ticket</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

With JavaScript to fill in the `$('#confirm-popup-subject')` and `$('#confirm-content')` before popping it up.

I used the following CSS overrides to get this:

```
#confirm-poup {
  top: 2%;
  bottom: 2%;
  overflow: initial;
}

#confirm-popup .modal-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 80%;
}
```

This makes the dialog take up most of the screen, and if it needs a scrollbar it has it. But now the customer is saying that they don't want it to be so big when it only has a few lines of text to display. They want it to be the minimum size it can be and still fit the body text in, but also to still have a scrollbar on the modal-body if the body text won't fit on the screen. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you simply mean that your popup should be of some fixed size and if your content is bigger then the default size then your model body should get the scroll instead of getting bigger.???

Comment: @ShalinPatel no I want it to expand as necessary, but once it gets to the biggest that will fit on the screen, then it will get a scrollbar just in the modal-body.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I got acceptable results if I change the CSS to this:

```
#confirm-popup {
  overflow: initial;
  top: 2%;
}
#confirm-popup .modal-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 70vh;
}
```

It's not perfect - it overlaps the screen if I make the browser too short - but it works for all supported browser sizes.